# Confirmation modal connecting to redux store using mapStateToProps gives an ERROR

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, redux, reactjs

I have a modal component. When the close button of the modal is clicked, I need to show up a confirmation modal. It has yes and no options.
This confirmataion component is connected to Redux store.

Everything was working fine till I connect the confirmation component into the store using `mapStateToProps`. After that only I started getting this error.

**Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(_class)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(_class)".
    at invariant (bundle.js:21701)**

I have attached the image below.

[image]

Here's my confirmation modal.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import AriaModal from 'react-aria-modal';
import { confirm } from '../util/confirm';
import { confirmable } from 'react-confirm';

class Confirmation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getApplicationNode = this.getApplicationNode.bind(this);
  }

  getApplicationNode = () => {
    return document.getElementById('application');
  }

  render() {
    console.log("rendering confirmation....");
    const {
     okLabbel = 'OK',
     cancelLabel = 'Cancel',
     title,
     confirmation,
     show,
     proceed,
     dismiss,
     cancel,
     enableEscape = true,
   } = this.props;

    const modal =
        <AriaModal
          titleText="demo one"
          onExit={this.deactivateModal}
          mounted={this.props.modalActive}
          initialFocus="#demo-one-deactivate"
          getApplicationNode={this.getApplicationNode}
          underlayStyle={{ paddingTop: '2em' }}
        >
          <div id="test-modal" className="background">
            <div className='model-title'>
              <h3 className='pe-title'>{title}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              {confirmation}
            </div>
            <footer className="modal-footer">
              <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={cancel}>{cancelLabel}</button>
              <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={proceed}>{okLabbel}</button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </AriaModal>;

    return (
      <div>
        {modal}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

Confirmation.propTypes = {
  okLabbel: PropTypes.string,
  cancelLabel: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  confirmation: PropTypes.string,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  proceed: PropTypes.func,     // called when ok button is clicked.
  cancel: PropTypes.func,      // called when cancel button is clicked.
  dismiss: PropTypes.func,     // called when backdrop is clicked or escaped.
  enableEscape: PropTypes.bool,
}

export default confirmable(Confirmation);
```

This is how I connected it to the store in a container component.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Confirmation from '../components/Confirmation';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("Calling mapStateToProps here!" + state.confirmation.modalActive);
  return { modalActive: state.confirmation.modalActive };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Confirmation);
```

You may see in the console the initial actioin on setting the visibility to true is working fine and the action is logged in the console like this.

```
{type: ON_CONFIRM, payload: true}
```

What's wrong with this `mapStateToProps`?

You may find the code for the project [here](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/modalcloseconfirmationdemo).

Why I am getting this error. What is going wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not rendering `Confirmation` component inside `app.js` file.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. Actually I want to popup confirmation modal only if the user closes the parent modal. So I only render parent modal? Do I need to render the confirmation modal in the app.js in order to connect with the store?

Comment: It is necessary that all components using store should be wrapped under `<Provider >` and it is the recommended approach. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#api). For your case, You can render  confirmation modal conditionally and that part of logic will go inside `Confirmation` component. it will check whether the parent modal is closed or not, if closed render the modal else simply return.

Comment: I understand your point. But rendering the confirmation upon closing the parent modal is the responsibility of that parent modal. How can I change the code elegantly to resolve this issue without letting the app component know that I am using Confirmation modal inside? Any suggestions?

Comment: "Is responsibility of the parent modal"  so the parent component should render the `Confirmation` modal. Let say a function is executed when close button is clicked then that function will be responsible for rendering the `Confirmation` component. So the `<ConnectedConfirmation {props you want to pass} /> ` will go inside render method of `DemoOne`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the react-confirm library. It renders your confirmation model in it's own component tree and not in your application's component tree. If you look at its [source code](https://github.com/haradakunihiko/react-confirm/blob/0.1.14/src/createConfirmation.js#L10), you can see that it use `ReactDOM.render` internally to create a new component tree. It's like you have two React application on the same page.

`mapStateToProps` of react-redux use React context to access the store. But as connected Confirmation component is rendered in a different component tree, connect HoC can't access the redux store via context.

The simplest solution would be finding another library which doesn't have this problem. But alternatively, you can inject your `context` manually into your connected Confirmation using a HoC.

Here is a HoC which you can use to inject the context to a component:

```
function withContext(WrappedComponent, context){

  class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
      return context;
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {};
  Object.keys(context).forEach(key => {
    ContextProvider.childContextTypes[key] = React.PropTypes.any.isRequired; 
  });

  return ContextProvider;
}
```

Let's assume that you render your connected Confirmation component in a component call Page. Then you can inject the context using above HoC like this.

```
class Page extends React.Component {

  //......

  static contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render(){

    const ConfirmationWithContext = withContext(ConnectedConfirmation, this.context);

    return (
      //.....
      <ConfirmationWithContext/> // with your props
      //.....
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's the library I used.https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-confirm It says "You can open a dialog component by calling function and it will be rendered outside your application." That is the culprit. How about removing that library and simply use a modal without wrapping it around using the confirm?

Comment: I don't know your use case. But if can manage it without the library, I think that's better than using suggested workaround which adds additional complexity to your application.

Comment: Yeah that's how I thought initially since HoC adds bit of complexity here just to inject the context. I'll give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by removing the comfirm library which I used earlier. I connected the parent Modal to the redux store using mapStateToProps insted of Comfirmation modal and rendered Confirmation by passing the activateModal as a property and rendered based on that. Now it's working as expected. Thanks for all the guidance and support !